# get specific rows from spark dataframe using certain column and list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, apache-spark

I have large spark dataframe 'df', (more than billion rows) made of

```
meta_info | date | comment
```

I also have a variable 'lst', where it stores all ids I'm interested in.

What would be the way to only retain rows where its id is included in lst?

```
df.where("meta_info".isin(lst)).show()
```

this is what I tried but it said 'string' doesn't have isin

Comment: What is `meta_info` ? You don't have the column in the dataframe.

Comment: Psidom, my bad. id = meta_info, I kinda mixed it up and confused myself XD

Comment: `df.where(df.meta_info.isin(lst))` ? You need `df.meta_info` to refer the column.

Answer (score 0):

First option is to rely on a join if your list is 'big':

```
data = [[value] for value in lst]
safelist = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=["meta_info"])
filtered = df.join(safelist, on='meta_info')
filtered.show()
```

Other option is to filter your dataset, but still, it can be relevant to broadcast your list in order to optimize data transmitted to your executors:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
blst = sc.broadcast(lst)
df.filter(F.col("meta_info").isin(blst.value)).show()
```

I would recommend to compare the two options on your dataset.